# tidy error - No tidy method for object of class dynlm

Tags: r

I have used the tidy/glance/augment functions from the broom package before with 'dynlm' functionality for time series data - that worked well!

Now I am trying to use it again on plain regression data (not necessarily time series data). the 'dynlm' function works and gives the right result for summary etc. but when I try to use the tidy(modelfit), it comes up with an error saying 'No tidy method for object of class dynlm'. But it works when I use 'lm' rather than 'dynlm'.

Any idea why? Am I missing something here? Does 'dynlm' work only with time series data? If yes, then why do I get the right model fit result?

As an example, here's the output from the tidy command on the 'lm' result object :-

```
tidy(modelfit[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]])
# A tibble: 7 x 5
  term                estimate    std.error statistic      p.value
  <chr>                  <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
1 (Intercept)    -0.0000485    0.0000675      -0.719  0.474       
2 Trend_1         0.00000242   0.000000382     6.34   0.0000000112
3 Temp_1         -0.00000269   0.00000488     -0.551  0.583       
4 Temp_2          0.0000000104 0.000000244     0.0424 0.966       
5 Temp_Recency_1 -0.00000791   0.00000176     -4.50   0.0000220   
6 Load_Lag_1      0.0000000944 0.0000000151    6.27   0.0000000157
7 Load_Recency_1  0.0000000321 0.0000000113    2.83   0.00578
```

Best regards

Deepak

Comment: But the error message is clear: 'No tidy method for object of class dynlm'. What do you expect? Im is a different class.

Comment: I didn't say that the error wasn't clear. I would like to know why does it work for one and not the other when the output returned from both are very nearly identical.

Comment: Hi @DeepakAgarwal I think Alexlok provided a sensible answer or guide. It's really not very clear what you are expecting as an answer. Maybe you would like to focus on that in your question instead of leaving it to the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `broom` is basically a collection of "if the class of the result is XXX, then do YYY to tidy it". You can see the collection that has been implemented [here](https://broom.tidymodels.org/articles/available-methods.html). It has 24 methods with "lm" in their names, but not `dynlm`.

If the behavior that a `dynlm-tidier` should have is obvious enough, you can [implement it yourself](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/develop/broom/) and eventually even submit it to be included in the package (if you're sure you have written good-quality code).

Comment: Alexlok <- Understand that! No worries. The question is that the class of the returned object is ('dynlm', 'lm') for 'dynlm' invokded command and ('lm') for 'lm' invoked command. Given that the classes are overlapping and if both the independent and the dependent variables are not time series data per se, then the output object class is the same from both 'dynlm' and 'lm', which is 'lm', right? In that case, shouldn't  the tidy function work for both and it does't. That was all that I was asking. I double checked & the class is 'lm' - still wondering doesn't it why doesn't it work for 'dynlm'!